# import an existing project in workspace

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the pullToRefresh example :

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

So, I download the code, and created two projects,
 the first one, `pullToRefresh` with the pulltorefresh code, and `pullToRefreshEx` with the pulltorefreshexample.

I tried to import the `pullToRefresh` project, but I got an error:

```
Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace
```

It exist, because I import "existing project in workspace", what am I doing bad?

Comment: In your workspace you already have the same project name. So change the projectname and try to import it

Comment: delete project from workspace. Keep it somewhere else and then import...

Comment: somewhere else is my workspace folder, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

uncheck the "**copy projects into workspace**" selectbox, and then click "**refresh**" button, you will be able to import the project

Comment: this is unchecked, I tried to check-uncheck and refresh and nothing happens

Comment: this is so simple , I can not understand why you dont solve simple problem

Answer (score 0):

I could never import projects into a workspace properly. I ended up doing this:

1. Put the sources in the correct folder.
2. In Eclipse create a new project (a general project) giving it the name of the folder.
3. Right click on the project, choose Android Tools | Fix Project Properties.
4. Right click on the project, go to Properties, select Java Build Path, and add the 'src' and 'gen' folders as 'source folders'.

Comment: you mean an android project with "a general project" doesn't you?

Comment: Don't create an android project, create a general project.

Answer (score 0):

one more possibility is that the project has an ambiguous name like "library", if you already have an existing  project with the same ambiguous name your eclipse will not allow importing it into the workspace.

try checking for that and renaming the existing projects to normal names that will represent the true meaning of their content.

(the obvious option is from the answers above)